# Type guards for types of arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

Using `typeof` type guards for non-array types is pretty straightforward (example from the [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)):

> ```
> function padLeft(value: string, padding: string | number) {
>     if (typeof padding === "number") {
>         return Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value;
>     }
>     if (typeof padding === "string") {
>         return padding + value;
>     }
>     throw new Error(`Expected string or number, got '${padding}'.`);
> }
> ```

However, when it comes to array types it gets more complicated.
I would assume that the following code would work:

```
function join(array: number[] | string[]): string {
    if (typeof array[0] === 'number') {
        return foo(array);
    } else {
        return bar(array)
    }
}

function foo(n: number[]): string {
    return n.join();
}

function bar(s: string[]): string {
    return s.join();
}
```

Seems quite simple to me: the expected type is either array of numbers or array of strings.
If the type of the first element in the array is `number` then the array is of type `number[]`. Otherwise, this is a strings array.

Unfortunately, TypeScript compiler is not that smart and I get a compilation error:

> Argument of type 'number[] | string[]' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'string[]'

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is **User-Defined Type Guards**.

You can define a type guard of your own that will determine whether the array is array of numbers or not:

```
function isNumbers(array: number[] | string[]): array is number[] {
    return typeof array[0] === 'number'
}
```

Read more about user defined type guards [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

The following is a working example of your code:

```
function join(array: number[] | string[]): string {
    if (isNumbers(array)) {
        return foo(array);
    } else {
        return bar(array)
    }
}

function foo(n: number[]): string {
    return n.join();
}

function bar(s: string[]): string {
    return s.join();
}

function isNumbers(array: number[] | string[]): array is number[] {
    return typeof array[0] === 'number'
}
```

TypeScript playground [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20join(array%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7C%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isNumbers(array))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20foo(array)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20bar(array)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(n%3A%20number%5B%5D)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20n.join()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bar(s%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20s.join()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isNumbers(array%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7C%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20array%20is%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20array%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(join(%5B1%2C%202%5D))%3B%0D%0Aalert(join(%5B'3'%2C'4'%5D))%3B).

Answer (score 10):

[JeB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49813444) was a very good start for me but I needed something a little more robust because I have to deal with arbitrary input. Here's what I came up with:

```
function isNumberArray(value : unknown) : value is number[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (value.some((v) => typeof v !== "number")) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I use for string array. I guess you could make it generic and test for any type:

```
export const isStringArray = (value: unknown) => {
  return Array.isArray(value) && value.every((val) => typeof val === "string");
};
```

Comment: This seems like a copy and reformat of my answer, except slower because it's using `every` instead of `some`. ‍♂️

Comment: Without the `value is string[]` part that function doesn't work as a type guard.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent documentation on Typescript's user-defined type guards in type predicates can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

As an addition to the chosen answer, according to the typescript docs, you can use type assertion when defining typeguards for custom types:

```ts
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```