# "typeof" check for arrays

Tags: typescript

Considering the `v` variable has this type:

```
number | number[] | MyType | MyType[]
```

and a function `myFunc` that accepts only `number | number[]`.

Why does TypeScript understand this check:

```
if(typeof v === "number"){
    myFunc(v);
}
```

but not this:

```
if((typeof v === "number") || ((v instanceof Array) && v.every((e) => typeof e === "number")))
    myFunc(v);
}
```

?

Comment: Could you give a [mre]? But in short: because it doesn't know `v.every((e) => typeof e === "number"))` narrows `v` to `number[]`; the inferred return type of the callback is just `boolean`, not a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (`e is number`).

Comment: Because the result of that `every` isn't used for type narrowing

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813443/type-guards-for-types-of-arrays

Comment: it is, didn't know about user-defined type guards. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic won't [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) down `number | number[] | MyType | MyType[]` to `number | number[]`. You'll have to define a custom type guard using a [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for that.

> [...] To define a user-defined type guard, we simply need to define a function whose return type is a type predicate. [...]  A predicate takes the form parameterName is Type, where parameterName must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature.

<sub>https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates</sub>

```
function isNumberOrNumberArray(
  value: any
): value is number | number[] {
  return (
    typeof value === "number" ||
    (Array.isArray(value) && value.every(e => typeof e === "number"))
  );
}
```

When using this function as a type guard (e. g. in an `if` statement) we can safely narrow a value down to `number | number[]`.

```
declare const unassignable: unique symbol;
type MyType = {[unassignable]: unknown};

declare const v: number | number[] | MyType | MyType[];
declare function myFunc(param: number | number[]): unknown;

function isNumberOrNumberArray(
  value: any
): value is number | number[] {
  return (
    typeof value === "number" ||
    (Array.isArray(value) && value.every(e => typeof e === "number"))
  );
}

if (isNumberOrNumberArray(v)) {
  myFunc(v); // works
}

if (
  typeof v === "number" ||
  (v instanceof Array && v.every(e => typeof e === "number"))
) {
  myFunc(v);
//       ~ Not assignable
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gVxVNaAlgOZ4BGEIAXDioQI7YJoCeAtmUhANwBQGLAA4IAsiwAqQhAF54AbwDaufEVJQKIALo1cAaxRIA7igC+fXqEiwEydFgBuNFNg4gY8AD7xnrmAs2e8GKSwoHBUv58ltBw8ABmuGAYhKjwbCwAYokAFIKwUGxOLmRugT4lfpoAlDoo+kYo5gkoSSko8IRoAHLFbgDyMD2+AIIwMFAs2bzw8PZQEEw0UCgsvDWz80wdaN697l7lbv7y0-BwGNgw7VMzMwLCSHEbCzLSsgBEhzDvnh6nM9lRuMWAA6TpAibZOYvKrwABkcOeTBBIHsbkmMgAfPB7iBHvBXh8vu8qlVTlU+CZeLxCE9sp0hhUBoy3BDJvZSScZuksi0oRTeFSaXTTrj8fZ4G8iXsfh4-gCJYQ7MswHinmz4Yj7Ci0TAMZLsWKnoT4J8ZaS1ly0pkchzKUA)